# How To get All File From Folder in Php + Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

> For Example i have One folder With Name

```
 Main Folder----| 
                 |
                 |
        |-----------------------|                
        |                       |
        |                       |
    Sub Folder 1              Subfolder 2
         |                      |
  |---------------|             |
  |               |          file 3.rar   
  |               |
file1.rar     file 2.rar
```

> Now I need To Reduce all necessaory Folder andNow I need Final Output Like Below is that Possible ?

```
 Main Folder
     |
     |
  file1.rar
  file2.rar
  file3.rar
```

Comment: _Now I need To ... is that Possible ?_ Yes it is! You need to code!

Comment: can You tell me how ?

Comment: Sorry but you write code. That's YOUR job. we just try help fix that code once you've written it.

Comment: Yes Bro I dont tell you to give me Code I just need some hint to  how to do this

Comment: I think the best hint is what you already have visualized above. Now its time to think about the logic, plan it and start to code. Nothing bad will happen to you if you try it

Comment: @bub your comments here really aren't helpful at all. You're essentially telling them to go and learn without giving them any pointers as to where to even start to learn about this.

Comment: @Wakeuphate Instead of accusing me, feel free to help :) Usually I am used to google first instead of waisting peoples time with questions that can be answered some where else. You see they put the question on hold as too broad...

Comment: @bub you'll see that I did below, it just hasn't been accepted yet.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [scandir](http://php.net/scandir) or [glob](http://php.net/glob) within PHP. These should give you a good starting point on how to run through directories, find files then [copy](http://php.net/copy) or [rename](http://php.net/rename) (this doesn't just rename files, it can be used to move them too) the files to their final destination.